# Get floating number match on regex using python

Tags: python, regex

String:

1. "Roaming Calls, **1.5** GB/Day 100 SMS/Day"
2. "Unlimited Loc/STD/Roaming Calls, **1**GB/Day"

I want to get the "1.5" and "1" by regex.

I use `r'.*([0-9.]+)(gb|GB| gb| GB)'` but only get "5" matched for the case 1.

Comment: Can you mention your full code here ?

Comment: `.*` is greedy and looks to backtrack with the higher priority. For what I see in your question it is not needed at all. You should skip it, using only `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s?(gb|GB)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this regex. This will match Non space characters begore GB

```
r'\S+(?=\s*(GB|gb|Gb|gB))'
```

Answer (score 2):

use Lookahead after the match to locate the float number before string `GB/Day`(case insensitive): `(?= GB/Day)`

`[\d.]+(?= GB/Day|GB/Day| gb/day|gb/day)`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XPB5YC/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix to the immediate problem with your pattern:

```
input = "Roaming Calls, 1.5 GB/Day 100 SMS/Day"
m0 = re.match(r'.*?([0-9.]+)?(gb|GB| gb| GB)', input)
if m0:
    print "match: ", m0.group(1)
```

Just make the dot appearing right before the capture group for the number lazy.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

For both float and other numbers you can try this :

```
import re
k = "Roaming Calls, 1.5 GB/Day 100 SMS/Day"
print(re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+",k))
```

if you want to find only float values go for this :

```
import re
k = "Roaming Calls, 1.5 GB/Day 100 SMS/Day"
print(re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+",k))
```

it will return a list of float numbers in that string like this :

> ['1.5']

Answer (score 0):

The issue that `.*` matches everything and leaves only 1 symbol for `[0-9.]+`. You can replace it with `.?` so it won't be that greedy:

```
.?([0-9.]+)(gb|GB| gb| GB)
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Noa8d9/1)